# Custom subnet mask while using DHCP

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to connect to an RPI on the same physical network over SSH. Normally, I'd do this with a simple `ip a`, `ssh xxx@ip`, but because of the network it doesn't work. There are several problems:

1. The IPs change quite often, at least once per day
2. Each device has a completely different IP (and I assume VLAN), despite being connected to the same physical router
3. The subnet mask is set to `255.255.255.0`, and because of (2)

If I first get an IP over DHCP, and then manually recreate that same IP, with a different subnet mask, then I'm able to connect successfully, but again only until the IP expires.

Normally, I would change the IP settings or something on the router, but since I have no control over the network (it's not mine), this is obviously not possible. I'd also get a static IP if I could, but again, not my network.

Overall, my question is: *Is it possible to change or somehow override the subnet mask on windows, while still using DHCP for IP assignment.*

## Edit:

I was unclear in my initial post. The network I'm connecting to is controlled by my accommodation, I can't access *anything* related to it at all (no router for me to access, no DHCP server, etc). I'm also pretty sure it *is* VLAN enabled, but again I can't check.

Comment: No. You'll have to change these settings on your router/DHCP server. Some ISPs that force you to use their routers do sometimes force different VLANs for different uses (ip iphones, internet, ip tv), but they typically group 2 ports per VLAN, maybe try different ports ?

Comment: See my edit, I don't have any access to it at all.

Comment: `Each device has a completely different IP` exactly how different? I mean like suppose you e.g. get 192.168.1.X on A and 192.168.2.X on B in one instance, do they always get 192.168.X.X anyway? (Or maybe always a 10.X.X.X? Or are your hosts assigned public IPs?) If changing the netmask give you access, you can probably config a static direct route on both of your hosts to get things work (e.g. a route for 192.168.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8).

Comment: @TomYan sometimes it's 192.168.1.0/24, sometimes 192.168.156.0/24, sometimes 192.168.243.0/24. This applies to all the devices, and because of the /24 subnet mask, it means that they'll get IPs on different subnets, and they won't talk to each uther because of the subnet mask, even though they physically are on the same network.

Configuring a static route sounds like it would solve it, but again I'm not too sure how to do that.

Comment: That really depends on the OS (or what you use to handle network management, if it's the case of Linux). For testing on Linux you can run something like `ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 dev interface_name`. On Windows you can add a persistent route with something like (IIRC) `route add -p 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 ip_on_the_interface`. (I have no idea whether Windows merely use `ip_on_the_interface` to resolve the interface to use in the direct/"on-link" route or the route will go away / work incorrectly when the assigned IP changes though.)

Comment: The key is, make sure it's a direct route (i.e., route with no actual/real gateway/nexthop).

Comment: @TomYan Could you please post your comment as a full-blown answer? Your comment has solved my problem and I'd like to mark it as the answer.

Comment: All I had to do was user `ipconfig` to look at the network configuration, and the help page of `route`. The ips are always `10.X.X.X`, hence the `10.0.0.0` and `MASK 255.0.0.0`. `10.170.7.254` is the gateway, `IF 4` is the ID of the network interface it's going over.

`route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.170.7.254 IF 4`

Really appreciate the help Tom!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change or somehow override the subnet mask on windows, while still using DHCP for IP assignment.

Generally, no. Windows either gets its interface IP address and subnet mask from DHCP or it is configured statically.

> The IPs change quite often, at least once per day

If possible, create reservations on the DHCP server for the devices you don't want to change addresses. Alternatively, it would help to extend lease time to a week or longer. If that isn't possible you need to deactivate that DHCP server and get a decent one. If that isn't possible either then ditch DHCP and configure all IP addresses manually.

> Each device has a completely different IP (and I assume VLAN), despite being connected to the same physical router

That's completely normal, each node on a subnet needs to use its own, unique IP address. They must all belong to the same subnet though (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24) - if not, you DHCP server is either not correctly configured or broken.

Unless your network is VLAN enabled (managed switch with explicit configuration and/or subinterfaces on the router), there are no VLANs.

Comment: > If that isn't possible you need to deactivate that DHCP server and get a decent one. If that isn't possible either then ditch DHCP and configure all IP addresses manually.

See my edit, unfortunately I can't because I'm forced to use their DHCP server, and if I manually configure my IP it stops working very quickly (it expires?)

Comment: @Anon We can't remotely fix what's broken...

Comment: > That's completely normal, each node on a subnet needs to use its own, unique IP address. They must all belong to the same subnet though (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24) - if not, you DHCP server is either not correctly configured or broken.

That's my point, sometimes it's 192.168.1.0/24, sometimes 192.168.156.0/24, sometimes 192.168.243.0/24 (i.e. the subnet does NOT match the IP changes). I can get two different IPs that can't talk to each other.

Comment: that's all good, I was just wondering if there was a way to override *just the subnet*, since that's really all that I can't work around